# Compiling less files not picking up global less variables

Tags: css, gruntjs, less, minify

I have a gruntjs file where I'm compiling less to css.. I've recently returned to a legacy project with the aim to improve performance.

My task is to instead of importing all the files in all.less, the goal is to have say articlePage.less and comments.less such as below;

```
'All.less', // Contains all the global variables
'component-commenting.less',
'component-popular-insights.less',
'component-reading-list.less'
```

I have these in my grunt file but the problem is, each of these files contains less variables for fonts, colours, media queries etc and don't pick up any of the global stuff.. Is there a way for these files to pick up the global variables in all.less or do i need to import the global variables into each of these files?

Comment: Just make a file called constants.less, or whatever you want to call it, and put all of your colors, fonts etc there. Then stick an import directive `@import "constants.less";` at the top of any of your other less files that need those values. Doesn't need to be any more complicated than that.

Comment: Thanks @sthurston, that was one potential route which was to just include the typography, colors etc to the top of each of the components but if there was two components on the page, then we've duplicate css, increasing the size. Then what happens with the constant variables imported in all.less.. When the page loads all.less, and potentially 2/3 component files are loaded with constant variables declared 2/3 times

Comment: Btw., note that Less variables are ["lazy evaluated"](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-evaluation) which leads to "Last Definition Wins" (aka LDW) rule. In other words if there're several variables of the same name in the same (e.g. global) scope - the last one has higher priority. Thus if (for example) both 'all.less' and 'component-reading-list.less' define varibales named `@boo` you shall put 'all.less' *after* 'component-reading-list.less' if you want 'all.less''s variables to be used (and yes then these variables will apply (in the same scope) to all of imported files).

Comment: See also [No !default, thanks!](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-default-variables) which basically illustrates the LDW (and it does not matter if a variable is defined in an imported file or not - all imported files share the same scope and it's the scope where they are imported in).

Answer (score -1):

Your component LESS files should contain a @import statement for your All.less file at the top of the file. Make sure to use the correct path for your import.

Consider refactoring the All.less to only contain the needed variables / media queries / etc.

```
@import './All.less';
```

Comment: @seven-phases-max Whoops.  Corrected the file extensions.  Thanks

Comment: The problem is not in extension but in different Less/Sass behavior (especially when it comes to variable scope/life-time) - e.g. see my comments  at the question (putting `All.less` at the top of imported files won't change anything and it's not really necessary).